# using javascript and css files in ASP.Net MVC View?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm having some trouble getting a jQuery plugin to work correctly in my MVC view.  Here's what it looks like at the moment: (I've copied all needed jQuery includes and css files into the /Scripts folder of the site)

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.MetaData.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.rating.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/Scripts/jquery.rating.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<input name="rating" type="radio" class="star" value="1"/>
<input name="rating" type="radio" class="star" value="2"/>
<input name="rating" type="radio" class="star" value="3"/>
<input name="rating" type="radio" class="star" value="4"/>
<input name="rating" type="radio" class="star" value="5"/>
</asp:Content>
```

The intellisense is squawking that the link element above can't be nested within a div tag (what div?) Nor can intellisense find the "star" class in any of the input tags.

When I navigate to the page in question I don't see the stars, just a list of radio buttons.  It's as if the jQuery stuff doesn't run.

Where should I put the script and link tags in an MVC view?  Anyone have small samples I can go by as an example?

I'm going over this example from "Professional ASP.Net MVC" from Wrox and the Ajax chapter leaves something to be desired, as the code is all snippets with no complete pages.  The Wrox website chapter code for this book also consists of the same snippets, one per text file, and is of no use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to put the `<link />` in the `<head>...</head>` section the script tags should be fine. You can put it in the head of a master page.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, everyone.  As it turns out, once I'd gotten the link and <script> tags in the right places in the contentheaders, I also needed to copy the gif files for the stars to my Scripts directory.  I should have seen that, though it would be nice to tell this javascript library where those images are, instead of having to put them in the same directory as the scripts...

Answer (score 2):

In your master page file, create a content placeholder in the head area. You can use this whenever you need to insert scripts and styles into specific views, meaning you won't deviate from the guidelines stating that this is where such files should go.

In your Site.Master file:

```
<head>
<!-- head stuff here -->
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server" />
</head>
```

In your view aspx file:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.MetaData.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.rating.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/Scripts/jquery.rating.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <input name="rating" type="radio" class="star" value="1"/>
    <input name="rating" type="radio" class="star" value="2"/>
    <input name="rating" type="radio" class="star" value="3"/>
    <input name="rating" type="radio" class="star" value="4"/>
    <input name="rating" type="radio" class="star" value="5"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also a useful excercise to use a Helper method to get the correct location of your Script and css files.

```
<script src="<%= Html.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js") %>
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

please check in  [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and see wat kind of response ur getting when u call the particular file ....if the script is rendered properly and for that particular page ...if no then please post the response and a copy ..

i got a similar problem when i was working with js in mvc i wasn't able to load the j query ...so for that i created a helper class which returns the absolute path for me

```
    public static string ResolveUrl(this HtmlHelper html, string virtualUrl)
    {
        Control con = new Control();
        var RelativeUrl = con.ResolveUrl(virtualUrl);
        if (!virtualUrl.StartsWith("~/"))
            return RelativeUrl;

        virtualUrl = virtualUrl.Remove(0, 2);

        string applicationPath = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(applicationPath) || !applicationPath.EndsWith("/"))
        {
            applicationPath = applicationPath + "/";
        }

        return applicationPath + virtualUrl;
      }
  }
```

and in my view i called the page like this ...

```
<script src="<%= Html.ResolveUrl("~") %>Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a master page for your site?  If so you could put all your include tags in the master page, it would then be available to all views using the master page.

Comment: Hi Fermin,

Thanks for your reply.  I am using a master page, and tried putting all the script and link tags above into it.  Intellisense didn't complain, but the page didn't render any stars. In fact, nothing rendered!

I'd also like to avoid putting these javascript files into Site.Master since only the one page will be using them.

Comment: Have you used a tool like <a hef="https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843">firebug</a> to see how the page is rendered and see if the javascript is loading fine.  Do you have your $(function() {} in your js file?